# On the physics tab when I switch to fire from smoke, and click back on domain it switches back to smoke?

Tags: physics

So I added a circle than went to "Object" than added the quick smoke effect, and then pressed "ALT+A" to start the animation at which point I do see smoke. This is where it gets weird.

I click on the domain than click on flow to adjust from smoke to fire. After that I click ALT+A and nothing happens. I than checked the other tabs "None" "Domain" etc, and when I went back to check "Flow" it switched the type back to smoke. I tried this a few different times, and restarted Blender 2.76. For some reason it won't switch to anything besides smoke... well it will, but it won't show anything and switches back once I'm on a different tab under physics.

Any insight into why this is happening would be great.

In summary: When I switch from smoke to fire or from smoke to fire+smoke nothing happens, and the value of smoke switches back to fire when I select a different tab besides "Flow".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this 100% solves my problem, but if I change flow type on the inner object inside the domain I can get something BESIDES smoke to appear.

Flow control: I changed this to fire on the OBJECT within the bounding domain and things seem to work after pressing ALT+A.

Domain: This has to be the active tab on the bounding box around the object which is emitting the smoke/fire etc.

Answer (score 0):

When you setup smoke and flow type to fire, for the object, try to setup the domain with "adaptative" and "high resolution". In my crappy machine (intel card), at least, this is needed to see "fire"...

Comment: That did nothing, but I am on to something.